# How to derive the formula from this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, formula-derivation

This is the schematic to measure the \$R_{iso}\$. There is a switch, Q2 for the measurement.
**I need to find how to derive the \$Y_{iso}\$ from this circuit schematic.**
To find it out, I tried to use KCL at the node \$V_{xI}\$ and \$V_{xII}\$.

i) When the switch is opened, \$Y_{iso} = {I_{iso}\over Vn-VxI}.\$
ii) When the switch is closed, \$Y_{iso} = {I_{iso}\over Vn-VxII}.\$

The fourth picture shows what I got after the KCL.
but I'm stucked to find the next step and the change (or add/convert) to final derived formula.

I don't get how the final derived formula has the ratio of  \$ V_{BATI} \over V_{BATII} \$ in the denominator.

Please please help me :)
Thank you

[image: The circuit with switch]

[image: The final derived formula of Yiso that I need to find how to derive it]

[image: The circuit when the switch opens and closes]

[image: The formula after I used KCL at VxI and VxII]

[image]

Comment: What do you think is the first step you need to take towards getting an answer? You don't show how you applied KCL, for example. There must have been the 1st equation you developed. Not a final one. But the very first step you took along the path. Can you show how you chose to approach a solution for this problem? What insight did you apply?

Comment: Also, may I assume that the batteries have their own conductances that must be accounted here as \$Y_n\$ and \$Y_p\$? (It's not entirely clear to me.)

Comment: @jonk I add the picture that how I try to solve. I tried to solve find the current through the Riso by the KCL at the node VxI and VxII. I'm not sure this is right step that the solution did. This could be wrong.

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure about your second question. You may think the battery Vp and Vn are some certain value. Also, since Rp = Ra+ Rb and Rn=Rc+Rd, then Yp is might be same as the admittance of Vp battery and  Yn is same as the admittance of Vn battery.

Comment: I guess I could use some additional explanatory text, then. I think my brain is getting closer to where yours is at. But I'm not certain it's in perfect synchrony. I'd like to see some discussion on your part about the meaning of \$Y\$. Is that always a *conductance*? (I think it is.) And if so, what precisely is the meaning of \$Y_n\$ and \$Y_p\$? And my sincere thanks for the additional graphics you added. That really does help. +1 now, as your question has greatly improved in my mind.

Comment: @jonk Oh yes, I always treated \$Y\$ as conductance. Also, in the second picture, the condition says 1) \$R_p=R_a + R_b \$ 2) \$R_n = R_c + R_d\$ 3) \$R_x = 1/Y_x\$
So that, I use \$R_n = 1/Y_n\$ and \$R_p = 1/Y_p \$ ... Or \$Y_p = {Y_aY_b \over Y_a+Y_b} \$

Comment: There must be more to the problem statement. Could you provide the missing pieces?

Comment: @john Unfortunately, this is all I have

Answer (score 1):

If there's no more information available, and that's a big if, considering that the answer seems to  indicate the voltage sources have some series resistance, then the circuit with the switch open simplifies to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8mpq0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
With the switch closed, the solution is a familiar voltage divider formula: Vx = Vn(Rb//Rn)/(Riso+Rb//Rn). Rearrange terms to find Riso.